# PDO won't execute update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update a row in mysql using `PDO` to do so, i have no idea why it doesn't execute. Everything seems to be correct, but it doesn't execute, neither does it generates any error.

First i get the values that i send via `$.ajax`

```
$idRequest = $_POST['idRequest'];
$dateStarted = $_POST['dateStarted'];
$requester = $_POST['requester'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$qaauthorization = $_POST['qaauthorization'];
$qengineer = $_POST['qengineer'];
$performer = $_POST['performer'];
$voltage = $_POST['voltage'];
$goal = $_POST['goal'];
$measurementunit = $_POST['measurementunit'];
$account = $_POST['account'];
$centercost = $_POST['centercost'];
$ela = $_POST['ela'];
$it = $_POST['it'];
$testtype = $_POST['testtype'];
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$part = $_POST['part'];
$objective = $_POST['objective'];
$production = $_POST['production'];
$reason = $_POST['reason'];
$specifications = $_POST['specifications'];
```

Then i create the query

```
 $queryRQ = "UPDATE
                request
            SET
                `idRequester` = ? , `idQEngineer` = ? , `RequestDate` = ? , `idModelNumber` = ?,`idPartDescription` = ? ,`idTestType` = ? , `ReasonForTesting` = ? ,
                `Quantity` =?,`Goal` = ?,`idMeasurementUnit` = ?, `Voltage` = ?, `AccountNumber` = ?, `CenterCost` = ?, `ELA` = ?,`ITNumber` = ?, `idPerformer` = ?, `DateStarted` = NOW(), `DateCompleted` = NULL,
                `Specifications` =?, `idObjective` = ?, `idProduction` = ?, `idBrand` = ?, `Available` = 1 , `Pending` = 0)
            WHERE
                idRequest = ?";
```

Finally when i `prepare` and `execute` the `$stmt` it seems as if nothing has happened, and it doesn't generate any error

```
$reqVals = array($requester,$qengineer,$dateStarted,$model,$part,$testtype,$reason,
                    $quantity,$goal,$measurementunit,$voltage,$account,$centercost,$ela,$it,$performer,
                    $specifications,$objective,$production,$brand, /* WHERE */ $idRequest);
$stmtRQ = $pdo->prepare($queryRQ);
$stmtRQ->execute($reqVals);
```

I'm reporting the error by surrounding everything with a `try - catch`:

```
try{
 // EVERYTHING
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo(json_encode($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You should check the return value of your execute - you're also not outputting any error message from the server.

Comment: it's also everything surrounded with `try{ .. }catch(PDOException $e){}` wich outputs it

Comment: You could also output the contents of `$pdo->errorInfo()`. I'm not sure, but I don't think PDO generates an exception if your query fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra NULL keyword which looks out of place...

```
`DateStarted` = NOW(), NULL,
                       ^^^^^
```

There's also a right paren that looks invalid ...

```
 `Pending` = 0)
              ^
```

For spotting these kinds of things, formatting SQL statements in a particular way (even if it is more lines) helps a lot... here's a malformed SQL statement that is equivalent to yours, it has the extraneous NULL keyword, and the unmatched closing (right) paren:

```
UPDATE request
   SET `idRequester`       = ?
     , `idQEngineer`       = ?
     , `RequestDate`       = ?
     , `idModelNumber`     = ?
     , `idPartDescription` = ?
     , `idTestType`        = ?
     , `ReasonForTesting`  = ?
     , `Quantity`          = ?
     , `Goal`              = ?
     , `idMeasurementUnit` = ?
     , `Voltage`           = ?
     , `AccountNumber`     = ?
     , `CenterCost`        = ?
     , `ELA`               = ?
     , `ITNumber`          = ?
     , `idPerformer`       = ?
     , `DateStarted`       = NOW()
     , NULL
     , `Specifications`    = ?
     , `idObjective`       = ?
     , `idProduction`      = ?
     , `idBrand`           = ?
     , `Available`         = 1
     , `Pending`           = 0
     )
 WHERE idRequest = ?
```

---

If this SQL statement is being sent to the database, the database is certainly raising an exception. The more fundamental problem is that your code is either not preparing this statement, or it's not exposing a SQL exception in the way you expect it to.